# How to use different layout for specific views in sails.js and angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sails.js

I have a Sails.js + Angular.js project. I am using a single layout for this project. But right now I got different html, and it's layout is totally different from the one I am using right now.

The current layout file I am using is the default one `layout.ejs` which located at views/layout.ejs. In the layout.ejs file, the header and footer are resuable throught the project, The body part which is `<div ng-view></div>`, I am using angular.js for this dynamic part. And the angular app file is like:

```
 function config($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/movie', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/movie-list.html',
    controller: 'MovieCtrl'
  }).when('/movie/:id', {
    templateUrl: '/templates/movie-detail.html',
    controller: 'MovieCtrl'
  })
}
```

Right now, I got 3 htmls which layout is completly different. I still want to add these new html as template file, and put them in the codes above. But how should I separate the layout and make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can use the following before sending data.

res.locals.layout = '';